# why button click not occur in typescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

could you please tell me why button click not occur in typescript ?

here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/z4vo5u5d/238/

```
 class Nav {
        private config:object;
        constructor(){
            this.config = {
                $navigationPanel : $('#navigationPanel ul'),
                $addItems:$('#adItems')
            }
        }

        init(){
            this.attachHandlers();
        }
        addItems(){
            alert('===')
            this.config.$navigationPanel.append('<li>tens</li>')
        }
        attachHandlers(){
            this.config.$addItems.on('click' ,this.addItems)
        }
    }

    $(function(){
        var n =new Nav();
        n.init();
    })
```

when I copy my code and run on this website 
http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

it gives error

> Property '$navigationPanel' does not exist on type 'object'.

Comment: its working there

Comment: where it is working ?

Comment: @PraveenRawat what is working, when i run the jsfiddler then i can see the error in the console

Answer (score 2):

Update your `attachHandlers` code like this:-

this is called [function prototype binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
attachHandlers(){
  this.config.$addItems.on('click' ,this.addItems.bind(this)) /* bind(this) added */
}
```

Note:-

`addItems` is a event callback function, it doesn't get the this reference to the `Nav` class. By binding `this` reference of `Nav` class while assigning click event handler the `addItems` function gets access to `Nav` class reference.

Comment: why we use bind in typescript ? why it give property not found Property '$navigationPanel' does not exist on type 'object'.

Comment: to bind  the event (click) to the current object

Comment: why it give property not found Property '$navigationPanel' does not exist on type 'object'.

Comment: @user944513  because a callback function din't refer `this` directly to get any class property.So you have to bind `this` as a reference to the class and then it will work

Comment: what is best practice .. ? how you write this code in typescript ?

Comment: i didn't get why  http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ give error when I copy my code

Answer (score 0):

When binding the event handler, you need to make sure that **this** is what you expect it to be within the **addItems** method scope. In your current iteration, **this** is equal to the **config object**.

To change the meaning of **this**, you can use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) as follows:

```
attachHandlers(){
    this.config.$addItems.on('click' , this.addItems.bind(this));
}
```

In that context, we're passing the class itself as the reference for **this** to the function, so when the handler is triggered, it will execute the expected method.

Comment: i didn't get why  http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ give error when I copy my code

Comment: Because TypeScript knows that when the call to addItems is made in that context, **this** is actually a reference to **this.config**, so what's actually being called is `this.config.config.$navigationPanel` (and this.config.config is already undefined).